# I just cannot make this JSON data appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm still new to getting JSON data and manipulating it, be easy with me. I seem to be making a successful call to the data, but listing the fields comes back with [object] instead of the actual fields. It's probably something stupid, but I've been trying every variation that I can think of to specify the fields and it's just causing errors in the console.

You can see the JSON data here: https://api.myjson.com/bins/10h45j.json

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/10h45j.json", function(data){
            $.each(data.Luthiers, function(i, field){
                $("#cheetos").append(field + "<br />");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div id="cheetos"></div>
```

Comment: Here's an alternate JSON with an array: https://api.myjson.com/bins/hpylj.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/10h45j.json", function(data){
            $.each(data.Luthiers, function(field){
                $("#cheetos").append(field + "<br />");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you - this is what I was looking for! I'm now trying to figure out how to call the individual fields within each item. I have a feeling my JSON file needs to be formatted with arrays or something of the like.

All of the items have unique names (and include spaces) so I can't really go back and specify Luthiers.(item).URL

Am I formatted incorrectly for making a proper database that can have each item filtered by things like Country, City, etc?

Comment: @delano: You could add some explanation to what change you did to get it working.

Comment: I think I've got it working now with this:

$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ew0pj.json", function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, field){
                $("#show-data").append(field.NAME + "<br />");
        });
    });
});

Answer (score 2):

Add `JSON.stringify` in order to, well, "stringify" the JSON object. Try the snippet below, you'll see your data is printed the way you expect :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/10h45j.json", function(data){
            $.each(data.Luthiers, function(i, field){
                $("#cheetos").append(JSON.stringify(field) + "<br />"); // add JSON.stringify()
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div id="cheetos"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked but the data returned all the fields in a block, I'm working towards making listings that are sortable so I need to figure out how to list the items and then their respective fields [URL, Name, etc].

Answer (score 1):

You can try some thing like this 
and here u guess you can fetch the individual items too .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/10h45j.json", function(data){
            $.each(data.Luthiers, function(i, field){
                $.each(field, function(j, subFields){
                 $("#cheetos").append(subFields + "<br />");
            });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div id="cheetos"></div>
```